# Check if a query has finished

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, dbi

I need to perform some queries on a rather large table, how do i check if the query has finished?

The main problem is that the queries can take up to 10 minutes and i want to tell the user, and hence the webbrowser, that its still running, so simply waiting for `$sth->fetch*` to finish is not an option as it will "pause" the script until there is data to be fetched.

I checked the documentation but there seems to be no function like `$dbh->has_finished()` or `$dbh->has_data()`.

Comment: As far as I know, `fetch` is blocking operation and you can't do anything until it finishes.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem and i am searcher for a function that i can ask "Is it done yet?" all the while i can send the browser and the user a "Still running, please wait".

Comment: You'll need job queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous database queries should be possible with an event loop. I suggest that you take a look at [AnyEvent::DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aDBI). The trick is to use a condition variable. The query is executed asynchronously. When the query is finishen it calls a callback sub that broadcasts on the condition variable. You can use `$cv->ready` for checking whether the query is finished.